# HAS_SUBNORM is 0: FTZ (flush to zero) shall be done before tininess detection or after tininess detection?

Tags: c, exception, floating-point, ieee-754, subnormal-numbers

Consider `1.1754944E-38f - 1.1754945E-38f` (both are normals).

If `HAS_SUBNORM is 1`, then the answer is `-1E-45f` (subnormal) and no exceptions are raised.

If `HAS_SUBNORM is 0`, then the answer is `-0.0f` (subnormal `-1E-45f` was flushed to zero). Question: shall `Underflow and Inexact` be raised?

IEEE 754-2008, 7.5 Underflow:

> The underflow exception shall be signaled when a tiny non-zero result is detected.

The tininess is detected:

- after rounding, or
- before rounding.

However, at which step FTZ (flush to zero) logic shall be executed:

- before tininess detection, or
- after tininess detection?

Reason of the question: some hardware does not support subnormal numbers, but *does raise* `Underflow and Inexact` in the example above. Meaning that such hardware does FTZ after tininess detection. I am wondering whether it is a correct behavior.

Comment: If an implementation does not support subnormal numbers, it does not conform to IEEE-754, and IEEE-754 rules about exceptions do not apply.