# HAS_SUBNORM is 0: "subnormal results" are determined before rounding or after rounding?

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding, c11, subnormal-numbers

C11, 5.2.4.2.2 Characteristics of floating types <float.h>, 10, footnote 26:

> Characterization as absent is intended if no floating-point operations produce subnormal results from non-subnormal inputs, even if the type format includes representations of subnormal numbers.

Here "subnormal results" are determined before rounding or after rounding?

Test shows that some implementations do it before rounding, some implementations do it after rounding.

Here is the test:

```
#if FLT_HAS_SUBNORM == 0
int subnorm_determ_method( void )
{
    volatile float f1 = FLT_MIN; /* 1.17549435e-38f */
    volatile float f2 = 1.0000001f;
    volatile float f3;
    int r;

    r = fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
    if ( r != 0 )        return -1; /* error: fesetround(FE_UPWARD) failed */
    f3 = f1 / f2;
    if ( f3 == FLT_MIN ) return 0; /* "subnormal results" are determined after rounding */
    if ( f3 == 0.0f )    return 1; /* "subnormal results" are determined before rounding */
    return -2; /* error: unexpected result */
}
#endif
```

UPD (after more research / experiments is / are done).

1. The exact place of execution of FTZ logic is irrelevant to this question: no matter if FTZ logic is executed before rounding or after rounding, the rounded (delivered) result is not a subnormal.
2. If an implementation does not support subnormal numbers, then such implementation does not conform to IEEE 754. Hence, such implementation is free to chose at which step the FTZ logic is executed. Experiments confirm that: different implementations configured with FTZ=1 (or with permanent FTZ=1) may execute FTZ logic at different steps, hence, producing different results: `±0.0` or `±<TYPE_PREFIX>_MIN`.
3. Extra: raising of floating-point exceptions in case of FTZ=1: the same story as in 2.: IEEE 754 nonconforming implementations are free to do what they want.

Comment: Your code does not show anything about whether some implementations determine whether a result is subnormal before rounding or after rounding.

Comment: A result is a value produced by an operation. It is not some intermediate value inside the operation. The words “no floating-point operations produce subnormal results from non-subnormal inputs” can only be about results after rounding.

Comment: @EricPostpischil _A result is a value produced by an operation_: I have the same view. However, Intel x86-64 and NVIDIA​ CUDA make me think about _intermediate value inside the operation_, because when using both x86-64 and CUDA configured with `FTZ=0` the `f3` is zero. Meaning that such implementations execute FTZ logic before rounding. How can you explain that? (Of course, the hardware does not follow the C standard.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Rephrasing your [previous conclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68269018/1778275): If an implementation does not support subnormal numbers, it does not conform to IEEE-754, and IEEE-754 rules about _anything_ do not apply. Meaning that such non-IEEE 754 implementations are free to chose whether FTZ logic is executed before rounding or after rounding. I see it this way.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Typo: ... x86-64 and CUDA configured with **`FTZ=1`** the `f3` is zero.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The Intel C++ Compiler Classic Developer Guide and Reference says: _Use the [Q]ftz option to flush denormal results to zero when the application is in the gradual underflow mode._ Here "denormal results" very possibly mean "rounded denormal results". However, x86-64 configured with `DAZ=1` may flush unrounded subnormal to zero even if rounded subnormal is normal (FLT_MIN).

Comment: Typo again: However, x86-64 configured with **`FTZ=1`** may flush ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No standard governs whether an implementation that chooses to flush subnormal values to zero does so based on whether mathematical result before rounding is subnormal or the result of rounding is subnormal.

Whichever choice an implementation makes in that regard, the quoted text concerns the delivered results. If no floating-point operation produces a subnormal result, then characterization as absent is intended.

Note that whether an implementation chooses to flush subnormal values to zero before or after rounding is irrelevant to this: In either case, an implementation will not deliver subnormal results. One that flushes subnormals after rounding will flush to zero all the results and only the results that would have been subnormal. One that flushes before rounding will flush to zero all the results that would have been subnormal and some that would have been normal. Both never deliver subnormal results.