# Does x86 support "before rounding" tininess detection?

Tags: x86, floating-point, intel, underflow

From experience I know that x86 has "after rounding" tininess detection (as [recommended by Annex U of 754r](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008_revision)).

However, does x86 support "before rounding" tininess detection as well? (I guess no.)

Extra: I guess that tininess detection method is pre-defined during the design of the hardware. However, I wonder whether there is any hardware that supports both tininess detection methods (switchable via an option).

Comment: x86 has separate bits in MXCSR (SSE/AVX FP control / status register) for DAZ (denormals-are-zero on input) and FTZ (flush-to-zero on output).  Typically (e.g. linking with `-ffast-math`) they're both set or both cleared, but are independent, which can matter for constants, or reading data from another thread (FPU context is per-thread) or from a file.  Is this what you were asking?

Comment: No, the DAZ and FTZ are irrelevant here. (Though, the FTZ logic may be executed as well before tininess detection and after tininess detection. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68269018/1778275) question. I don't remember whether x86 executes FTZ logic before tininess detection or after tininess detection.) The question is not about denormals. The question is about tininess detection.

Comment: @PeterCordes See ["I discovered a case where, even though tininess is set to be detected after rounding..."](http://www.jhauser.us/arithmetic/SoftFloat-3/doc/SoftFloat-FAQ.html).

Comment: Ah I see, "tininess detection" as part of Underflow detection.  Thanks for the links, I didn't know those details.  There isn't a control bit in MXCSR for it.  https://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/simd/sse.php lists the bits: rounding direction, FTZ/DAZ, and exception mask + flag bits for each FP exception.  I'm not aware of any later ISA extensions adding more control bits.

Comment: There is probably no hardware that supports both kinds to tininess detection, as it would be too expensive for something that may not be very important in practice, except for reproducibility. Note that in 2007, Michel Hack posted a mail to the stds-754 about emulating "after rounding" on a "before rounding" machine and emulating "before rounding" on an "after rounding" machine.

Comment: The answer to the titular question is"no". For what it is worth, I have never come across a processor architecture that gives programmers a choice, rather this is a hardware design decision: SPARC, Power, ARM detect tininess before rounding, while MIPS, x86, and RISC-V detect tininess after rounding. To my knowledge, the IEEE-754 standard in its latest incarnation still allows both methods. Obviously one could emulate either method, although I fail to see a use case for that outside of FPU validation suites.

Comment: @vinc17 Would you happen to have a link if it is available online? The IEEE-754 email archive used to be available online (I last searched through it a few years ago to find out why tanPi was omitted from the standard, while sinPi and cosPi were included), but I cannot find it anymore. A search for "Michel Hack" plus "tiny" or "tininess" did not turn up anything relevant.

Comment: @njuffa I've eventually found the [message archived on Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20090107223807/http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/email/msg03727.html).

Comment: @njuffa Re: "The answer to the titular question is"no": then consider posting an answer to this question (so I can accept it).

Comment: @njuffa Re: "I have never come across a processor architecture that gives programmers a choice": it seems that Arm does: `// Deal with flush-to-zero and underflow after rounding if FPCR.AH == '1'.` and `// Underflow occurs if exponent is too small before rounding, and result is inexact or the Underflow exception is trapped. This applies before rounding if FPCR.AH != '1'.` These are the fragments of the `FPRoundBase` pseudocode taken from [here](https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/exploration-tools) (section "Arm A64 Instruction Set Architecture", button "Download XML").

Comment: @vinc17 Re: "There is probably no hardware that supports both kinds to tininess detection": it seems that Arm does. See my prev. comment.

Comment: @pmor `FPCR.AH` seems to be used when flushing to zero is enabled ("the test for a denormalized number for the purpose of flushing the output to zero"). So this is different from the IEEE 754 rules.

Comment: @njuffa Do you know / remember _when_ x86 executes FTZ logic: before rounding, or in between rounding and tininess detection, or after tininess detection?

Comment: @vinc17 See my prev. comment. Perhaps you know?

Comment: @njuffa Re: "ARM detect tininess before rounding": was it _always_ before rounding across the entire ARM architecture family?

Comment: @njuffa Re: "SSE simply examines the exponent of the raw result prior to rounding": are you sure that SSE does it prior to rounding? Example: `0x1.fffffcp-127f * 0x1.000002p+0f` in my x86 software model produces before rounding `0x1.fffffffffff8p-127`. The exponent is -127, which is less that the min exp (-126). Hence, it flushes to zero. However, real x86 with FTZ=1 produces `1.1754944E-38f` (which is a non-zero). Hence, I wonder whether real x86 
 executes FTZ logic before rounding. Note that my x86 software model may be buggy.